# Apache Camel Kafka : how to set property "delivery.request.ms" on the Producer config

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am trying to set the `delivery.timeout.ms` property on the Producer Configuration however I can't find any suitable (Camel Component) Option under the Camel Kafka component doc page.

I was expecting to see a `deliveryTimeoutMs` option to be available (just like the requestTimeoutMs is to request.timeout.ms) but it just isn't there.

According to the camel-kafka api page there's no method available, across all versions, so is this option just not supported via Camel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Producer configuration `delivery.timeout.ms` has been added to the KafkaProducer configurations only in recent versions of Kafka. As I understand the documentation on [Kafka Camel Options](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html#_options) you would then need to add the prefix "additionalProperties" at the beginning, like this:

```
additionalProperties.delivery.timeout.ms
```

When changing the delivery timeout make sure to follow the recommendation: "The value of this config should be greater than or equal to the sum of `request.timeout.ms` and `linger.ms`."

The exakt description on Kafka Camel Options is

> "Sets additional properties for either kafka consumer or kafka producer in case they can’t be set directly on the camel configurations (e.g: **new Kafka properties that are not reflected yet in Camel configurations**), the properties have to be prefixed with additionalProperties."

Comment: Thats mike that seems like the way to go. I must have missed that in the docs. In any case looks like the `setAdditionalProperties` method is only available from camel-kafka version 3.1.0. I'm on an inferior version hence getting the `Unknown parameters` exception. I will have to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The stock class `org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConfiguration` does not suppport `delivery.timeout.max`. But you can use a proxy class wraps a KafkaConfiguration instance in order to add that config. My suggestion is using the class `org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor`, implement method `intercept()` to return the extra config `delivery.timeout.max`

Comment: I actually ended up doing something similar to this in the end.

Comment: Can you please let me know how you were able to add additional properties using MethodInterceptor. Due to certain dependencies I cannot upgrade from 2.x to 3.x. I need to add Sasl Login Callback Handler and I am not able to do it in camel 2.x

Comment: @JobinThoma: you need to implement the intercept() method. Check if the invocation is on createProducerProperties() and add 1 more element to the property before returning it. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0417__Spring/ImplementsMethodInterceptor.htm. I don't have the concrete code because I already left that company :D